# Defining record type in Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, record-type

I need some help, I have the following trigger, however I get the following error message “Error: Compile Error: expecting a right parentheses, found 'Integer' at line 5 column 8”
What I am trying to do, is just make this trigger work for this one record type.

Record type ID = '012R00000004wJv'

My trigger is

```
trigger ObjectNameCheckProducts on Campaign (before insert, before update) {
  for(Campaign o : Trigger.New){

    If(o.Campaign.RecordType == '012R00000004wJv'
    Integer counter = 0;

    if(o.Institutional_Products_A_G__c != null) 
       counter += o.Institutional_Products_A_G__c.split(';').size();
    if(o.Institutional_Products_G_Z__c != null)
       counter += o.Institutional_Products_G_Z__c.split(';').size();
    if(o.Intermediary_Products_A_F__c != null)
       counter += o.Intermediary_Products_A_F__c.split(';').size();
    if(o.Intermediary_Products_G_L__c != null)
       counter += o.Intermediary_Products_G_L__c.split(';').size();
    if(o.Intermediary_Products_M_Z__c != null)
       counter += o.Intermediary_Products_M_Z__c.split(';').size();

    if(counter > 5) o.addError('Max 5 values can be selected from Product lists');
 }
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Compile Error: **expecting a right parentheses**, found 'Integer'

and

> ```
> If(o.Campaign.RecordType == '012R00000004wJv'
> ```

Looks like your if statement is missing a right parentheses.  Note that the full error message say that it found 'Integer' on the line after (line 5) the if statement - with no closing parentheses at the end of line 4, the parser kept going until it found something that didn't belong in an if statement.  If you don't see the error on the line indicated, always look at the line(s) directly above.

Also, the field you need to check is `RecordTypeId`, not `RecordType` (see [reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/Content/sforce_api_objects_campaign.htm)).  Try this:

```
If(o.Campaign.RecordTypeId == '012R00000004wJv')
```

However, you shouldn't be hardcoding a record type id (or any id) into your code.  Instead, look up the record type id by name.  You could query the RecordType table, but there's a better way ([reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_Schema_RecordTypeInfo.htm#apex_class_Schema_RecordTypeInfo)):

```
trigger ObjectNameCheckProducts on Campaign (before insert, before update) {
  // Look up record type id
  String recordTypeName = 'Long-Term Strategic Products'; // <-- Change this to your record type name
  Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtMapByName = Schema.SObjectType.Campaign.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
  Schema.RecordTypeInfo rtInfo =  rtMapByName.get(recordTypeName);
  id recordTypeId = rtInfo.getRecordTypeId();

  for(Campaign o : Trigger.New){
    if(o.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId) {
      Integer counter = 0;

      if(o.Institutional_Products_A_G__c != null) 
        counter += o.Institutional_Products_A_G__c.split(';').size();
      if(o.Institutional_Products_G_Z__c != null)
        counter += o.Institutional_Products_G_Z__c.split(';').size();
      if(o.Intermediary_Products_A_F__c != null)
        counter += o.Intermediary_Products_A_F__c.split(';').size();
      if(o.Intermediary_Products_G_L__c != null)
        counter += o.Intermediary_Products_G_L__c.split(';').size();
      if(o.Intermediary_Products_M_Z__c != null)
        counter += o.Intermediary_Products_M_Z__c.split(';').size();

      if(counter > 5) o.addError('Max 5 values can be selected from Product lists');
    }
  }
}
```

Finally - Note the added braces after the initial if, wrapping the other if statements.

Comment: @ jason Clark
Where do i put
String recordTypeName = 'Long-Term Strategic Products' // <-- Change this to your record type name
Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtMapByName = Schema.Campaign.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
Schema.RecordTypeInfo rtInfo =  rtMapByName.get(recordTypeName);
id recordTypeId = rtInfo.getRecordTypeId();

and the 

if(o.Campaign.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId) 
into my trigger ?

Comment: Anywhere before you use it.  In this case, it must be before the if statement; before the for is best.  I've updated my answer to show the full trigger.

Comment: @ Jason Clark, if i use your trigger above i get the following

Error: Compile Error: expecting a semi-colon, found 'Map' at line 4 column 2

Comment: See my original advice; check the line before the error :)  On the line before line 4, `String recordTypeName = 'Long-Term Strategic Products'`, I forgot the semicolon.  I've updated the code in my answer.

Comment: @ jason Clark 
Thanks for providing update but i now get the following :(

 Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: Schema.Campaign.getRecordTypeInfosByName() at line 4 column 51

Comment: Apologies, this is what happens when I code from memory :)  See the updated code; `Schema.Campaign` should have been `Schema.SObjectType.Campaign`.  See my reference link for example code in the Apex documentation.

Comment: i know get 
Error: Compile Error: Invalid foreign key relationship: Campaign.Campaign at line 9 column 8

Comment: Ah, bug in your original code I overlooked.  See updated answer; in first `if` statement, `o.Campaign.RecordTypeId` should have been `o.RecordTypeId`.

Comment: @ Jason Clark Thank you :)
If i want it to apply to more than one recordname

would i do the following 

recordTypeName = 'Long-Term Strategic Products', 'ABC';

Comment: No, that wont work.  You'll need to get the set of recordtype ids and test if your current record's recordtype is in the set.  If you don't know how, please post a new question.  If I've answered your original question, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark icon.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to implement this Maximum 5 check for the given record type.  If so, you'll need to encompass all the counter increment logic in the if statement (see my edit below).

Furthermore, hardcoding Ids is a terrible idea and worst practice.  Either switch the RecordType check to use a Custom Setting instead, or use an additional query to fetch the Record Type Id before looping over the trigger results.

More on custom settings here: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm

```
trigger ObjectNameCheckProducts on Campaign (before insert, before update) {
    for(Campaign o : Trigger.New){

    //Assuming you have created a custom hierarchy setting with CampaignRecordType__c field
        if(o.Campaign.RecordType ==  Custom_Setting__c.getInstance().CampaignRecordType__c){ 
            Integer counter = 0;

            if(o.Institutional_Products_A_G__c != null) 
                counter += o.Institutional_Products_A_G__c.split(';').size();
            if(o.Institutional_Products_G_Z__c != null)
                counter += o.Institutional_Products_G_Z__c.split(';').size();
            if(o.Intermediary_Products_A_F__c != null)
                counter += o.Intermediary_Products_A_F__c.split(';').size();
            if(o.Intermediary_Products_G_L__c != null)
                counter += o.Intermediary_Products_G_L__c.split(';').size();
            if(o.Intermediary_Products_M_Z__c != null)
                counter += o.Intermediary_Products_M_Z__c.split(';').size();

            if(counter > 5) o.addError('Max 5 values can be selected from Product lists');
        }
    }    
}
```

Alternatively, here is what you could do instead, with querying for recordtype.developername:

```
trigger ObjectNameCheckProducts on Campaign (before insert, before update) {

    Id recordTypeId = [Select Id From RecordType Where SObjectType = 'Campaign' And DeveloperName='Your RT's dev name'].Id;

    for(Campaign o : Trigger.New){
        if(o.Campaign.RecordType == recordTypeId){ 
            Integer counter = 0;

            if(o.Institutional_Products_A_G__c != null) 
                counter += o.Institutional_Products_A_G__c.split(';').size();
            if(o.Institutional_Products_G_Z__c != null)
                counter += o.Institutional_Products_G_Z__c.split(';').size();
            if(o.Intermediary_Products_A_F__c != null)
                counter += o.Intermediary_Products_A_F__c.split(';').size();
            if(o.Intermediary_Products_G_L__c != null)
                counter += o.Intermediary_Products_G_L__c.split(';').size();
            if(o.Intermediary_Products_M_Z__c != null)
                counter += o.Intermediary_Products_M_Z__c.split(';').size();

            if(counter > 5) o.addError('Max 5 values can be selected from Product lists');
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: @ James loghry, im new to apex i dont mind using the id which is 012R00000004wJv or record type label "Long-Term Strategic Products"
I just dont know where to put it in the trigger

Comment: The issue with hard coding ids in your code is that Ids change between environments.  Once you deploy this code and the RecordType to production, the Id of the record type will change, and your code will be broken.  You can grab the DeveloperName of the Record Type by either going into the Record Type in your Salesforce Setup UI, or doing a query using execute anonymous System.debug([Select DeveloperName From RecordType Where Id='012R00000004wJv']); and then plug that into the text where I show 'Your RT's dev name'

Comment: Your query example assumes that no other object has a record type of the same name - you should add a criteria for `SObjectType = 'Campaign`, or use `getRecordTypeInfosByName()`

Comment: Good point Jason, I've updated the query.

Comment: You guys have confused me :( 
I understand hard  coding the ids is bad practice, but only method i know. Also i know the IDS change between enviroments. However i can live with that as i can change the ID when in live

Comment: 'changing the ID when in live' is an invitation to disaster.  Don't be confused:  There are several methods for avoiding hardcoded ids in code:  1.  Move the id into a custom setting.  This is James' first example.  However, you still need to update each environment.  2.  Query the RecordType table.  This is James' second example.  3.  Use the Schema object and `getRecordTypeInfosByName()`.  This is my example (see my answer).  This uses information about your org's schema that is cached by apex, and so avoids a SOQL query against your limits.

Comment: @ Jason Clark. I bought my self an introduction to apex book today so hopefully when it arrives i can get up to speed